# Assigning a checklist in Trello to a specific member

Tags: trello

Can you assign a checklist item to a member in Trello?

I have read through the guide and haven't found any way to do it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's the card in the Trello development board: https://trello.com/c/p2D8Zlxd You can vote there, I think it will be even more effective than voting on this question :)

Answer (score 1):

No, right now assignment is only at the card level. But it's a neat idea and we'll consider it! It sounds good for a plugin.